# show hide button in unity using c#

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I have 15 buttons on my screen at onClick event am fetching the button and hiding that button using

```
EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.SetActive(false);
```

now at the end i have to show buttons again so i am using

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
 {
     tag1 = "Button" + (i + 1);
     GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(tag1).SetActive(true);
     Debug.Log("done");
 }
```

Loop is giving error becuase it is not able to find object which has been hidden or setActive(false) from other references [unity forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-turn-on-off-button-visibility.290317/#post-1916554) i see same solution 
but i don't know why it is not working in my case

> i know issue is with "FindGameObjectWithTag" function i will have to replace it with some other

any help will be appreciated
 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
// in void Start
objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag (tag);

// void Update()
foreach (GameObject objs in obj) {
    obj.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Find` operation are costly operations: try to avoid them.

Make a public `List` and assign your buttons to that `List` and then iterate the `List`.

```
   public List<GameObject> allButton; // it will show in your inspector assign (Drag and 
                                      // Drop) all your buttons to this list. 

   public void ShowAllButtons(){

      for(int index=0; index < allButton.Count; index++ ){
         allButton..SetActive(true);
      }

   }
```